# Does anyone use a standard inertia message type?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm passing around dynamical properties (masses, inertias, etc) and there's no standard ROS message for a rigid body inertia with a coordinate frame and timestamp. Something like the following would be good (and simple):

**Inertia.msg**

```
# Mass [kg]
Float64 m
# First mass moment [kg-m]
geometry_msgs/Vector3 h
# Inertia Tensor [kg-m^2]
#     | ixx ixy ixz |
# I = | ixy iyy iyz |
#     | ixz iyz izz |
Float64 ixx
Float64 ixy
Float64 ixz
Float64 iyy
Float64 iyz
Float64 izz
```

**InertiaStamped.msg**

```
Header header
Inertia inertia
```

Anyone already using something like this? Maybe we could standardize it?

***Update:** Changed representation to use first mass moment instead of center of mass.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122126/does-anyone-use-a-standard-inertia-message-type?/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like a good idea.  Maybe propose it to https://github.com/ros/common_msgs ?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0